# Trying to achieve runtime value of namespace of datastore in dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

i am trying to fetch data from datastore from different namespace using runtime valueprovider in dataflow template.

## Set Runtime ValueProvider

```
class CatalaugeOption(PipelineOptions):
        @classmethod
        def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
             parser.add_value_provider_argument('--partner', default='', dest='partner', help='current date directory')

        my_options = options.view_as(CatalaugeOption)
        parser.add_argument('--kind', dest='kind', default='Product', help='Datastore Kind')
        known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
```

## Read Data From Datastore

```
with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        req_options = p.options.get_all_options()
        project = req_options['project']
        namespace = my_options.partner
        kind = known_args.kind
        query = query_pb2.Query()
        query.kind.add().name = kind
        protobufs = p | 'Read From Datastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(
            project, query, namespace=namespace)
         p.run()
        return
```

ValueError:Invalid DisplayDataItem. Value RuntimeValueProvider(option: partner, type: str, default_value: '') is of an unsupported type.

Comment: The error is odd, perhaps you passed type=None to add_value_provider_argument()? I also see that you're using my_options.namespace directly, but when it's passed as a runtime value you need to call `.get()` on it. See this example: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/pipeline-option-patterns/

Comment: change: 
parser.add_value_provider_argument('--partner', default='', dest='partner', help='current date directory',type='str')

namespace = my_options.partner.get()
error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Comment: It should type=str (without the quotes around str). In any case type-str is the default if not specified. Try "namespace = my_options.partner.get()"

Comment: change: type='str' to type=str
error: apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: partner, type: str, default_value: '').get() not called from a runtime context

Comment: I believe understand the issue now. Your usage is correct, but ReadFromDatastore doesn't support ValueProvider values for namespace. I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7810

Comment: From what I understand, the namespace should be specified in the Query type, and not the ReadFromDatastore class https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1new/types.py#L45. However, this namespace doesn't allow for ValueProvider usage either. Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, this functionality has been merged into Apache Beam master branch and should be part of the upcoming 2.19.0 release.

https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10683
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7810

Comment: 2.20.0 it is! Cheers.